# Maven Compile failed, cannot find symbol

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean) did not solve my problem...I'm sure there is no spelling mistakes or something else, the Idea can run the application successfully sometimes, but not all the times.It may have some mistakes in POM file and I didn't find out. According to the answer in floor 2 by dreamt, it passed the maven compilation, but what if I insist to put it as a child of web-common?

I'm not quite sure what's the key problem. The compilation problem is occured while compiling ref-model, the constants package was missing which was inherited from `web-common-model` which was depended on `web-common-enums`.

I'm developing an application with springboot.

the project structure is shown below:

```
TestSplitCommon
    |____web-common
    |         |___web-common-enums
    |         |            |
    |         |___web-common-model
    |                      |____ref-model
    |
    |____other-service(which has dependency in web-common)
```

but I have found something wrong to my maven while compiling.

While installing by command `mvn clean install` it shows `cannot find symbol Constants`. However, the missing symbol `Constants` was specified in `web-common-enums`, and also, the dependency `web-common-enums` is properly set in the pom of`web-common-model` and such code is reachable in IDE.
[image]

I don't know how to set `ref-model` as a dependency of other-service...

below is part of my code, and you can also get it in my [source code](https://github.com/WilliamChen-luckbob/SplitCommonDemo)

parent pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.wwstation</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestSplitCommon</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>web-common</module>
        <module>other-service</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>30.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

web-common pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>TestSplitCommon</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.wwstation</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>web-common</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>web-common-enums</module>
        <module>web-common-model</module>

    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <layout>
                        NONE
                    </layout>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

ref-model pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>web-common</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.wwstation</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>web-common-model</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>ref-model</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wwstation</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-common-enums</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <layout>
                        NONE
                    </layout>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

web-common-enum  pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>web-common</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.wwstation</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>web-common-enums</artifactId>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <layout>
                        NONE
                    </layout>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

other-service pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>TestSplitCommon</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.wwstation</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>other-service</artifactId>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wwstation</groupId>
            <artifactId>ref-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <goals>
                    <goal>
                        repackage
                    </goal>
                </goals>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Constant class in web-common-enums

```
package com.wwstation.common.constants;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

/**
 * 常量值
 *
 * @author william
 * @description
 * @Date: 2021-02-17 11:56
 */
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Constants {
    public static final String commonString="commonString";
}
```

a simple class in ref-model

```
package com.wwstation.common;

import com.wwstation.common.constants.Constants;

/**
 * @author william
 * @description
 * @Date: 2022-01-28 12:04
 */
public class TestClass {
    public static void test() {
        System.out.println(Constants.commonString);
    }
}
```

main class in other-service

```
package com.wwstation.other_service;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

/**
 * @author william
 * @description
 * @Date: 2022-01-28 14:09
 */
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.wwstation","com.wwstation.common"})
public class OtherServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OtherServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

test component in other-service

```
package com.wwstation.other_service.components;


import com.wwstation.common.TestClass;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

/**
 * @author william
 * @description
 * @Date: 2022-01-28 14:12
 */
@Component
public class TestComponent {

    @PostConstruct
    public void initAndPrint() {
        TestClass.test();
    }
}
```

And this is the error console:

```
NFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\TestSplitCommon\web-common\web-common-model\ref-model\target\classes
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#afterRebuildExecution
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/TestSplitCommon/web-common/web-common-model/ref-model/src/main/java/com/wwstation/common_ref_model/TestClass.java:[3,33] 程序包com.wwstation.commonenums不存在
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for TestSplitCommon 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] TestSplitCommon .................................... SUCCESS [  0.462 s]
[INFO] web-common ......................................... SUCCESS [  1.136 s]
[INFO] web-common-enums ................................... SUCCESS [  6.179 s]
[INFO] web-common-model ................................... SUCCESS [  0.387 s]
[INFO] ref-model .......................................... FAILURE [  2.855 s]
[INFO] other-service ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11.571 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-01-28T16:27:38+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project ref-model: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /D:/TestSplitCommon/web-common/web-common-model/ref-model/src/main/java/com/wwstation/common_ref_model/TestClass.java:[3,33] 程序包com.wwstation.commonenums不存在
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project ref-model: Compi
lation failure
/D:/TestSplitCommon/web-common/web-common-model/ref-model/src/main/java/com/wwstation/common_ref_model/TestClass.java:[3,33] 程序包com.wwstation.commonenums不存在

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
/D:/TestSplitCommon/web-common/web-common-model/ref-model/src/main/java/com/wwstation/common_ref_model/TestClass.java:[3,33] 程序包com.wwstation.commonenums不存在

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1220)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:187)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :ref-model
```

Comment: Without a [mre] this is hard to diagnose.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel the source code was [here](https://github.com/WilliamChen-luckbob/SplitCommonDemo). you can get it and have a look, I have made a simple demo to print a simple word in terminal, it will lead to my problem.

Comment: A question should be self-contained and not rely on external links for its [mre].

Comment: its hard to say where the problem is, so I pasted all my source code into this question. And the demo is the minimal reproducible example, the problem will not reproduced without any of the modules....

Answer (score 1):

I removed the relationship between 'web-common' module and 'web-common-enums' module on pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<groupId>com.wwstation</groupId>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<artifactId>web-common-enums</artifactId>
</project>
```

located in '${root}/web-common/web-common-enums/pom.xml'.

Secondly, execute

```
mvn install
```

on web-common-enums module.

Finally, execute

```
mvn compile
```

on ref-model module. It worked.

Comment: right, But this is just a simple demo, in my production situation I have some dependencies from it's parent `web-common`. And I have found that maven is not always failed to build in my situation, sometimes it will succeed.

Comment: And it also will succeed by several times with this demo. I don't know if it is related to my package path. e.g. classes was from the same package name but in different module.

Answer (score 0):

OMG! just remove all the plugins in web-common and it's child modules.....